Пустое пространство при переносе строки
На данном скриншоте видно как переносится текст, но меня не устраивает пустое синее пространство возле самого переноса. возможно сделать так, чтобы оно прижималось к тексту?


.wrapper{
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  max-width: 1200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.text{
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
<div className='wrapper'>
  <p className='text'>
      пример переносимого текста
  </p>
</div>





как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Какой вы хотите результат в последнем примере?

Добавьте text-justify: inter-character

есть такое свойство? подсказок нет и браузер не распознает. результат хочу получить как на первом скриншоте, только без пустого пространства из-за переноса строки. видимо text-align: justify не подходит, он создает большое пространство между словами.

text-align: justify,
text-justify: inter-character:


<div style="width: 20em;">
  <p style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-character;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
</div>




спасибо большое, помогло. но есть другие способы?

потому что если на строке будет 2 слова, между ними очень большое расстояние

Последняя строка параграфа выравнивается влево. Этого обычно достаточно. Если у вас узкая колонка, то тогда проблема. Но тогда вопрос: чего вы хотите в узкой колонке?

влево, да. но, к сожалению, не могу приложить скриншот, где слов на первой строке два, между которыми большое расстояние

давайте обновлю пост и приложу скриншот?

Да, конечно, так и сделайте.

text-justify: inter-character: - это пока только FF поддерживает

Можно к text-align: justify добавить word-break: break-all и тогда будет перенос побуквенно. Но грамматически это не правильно думаю).


p {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align: justify;
}
<p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя</p>




к сожалению побуквенно тоже не подходит(

@сонямармеладова ну значит нужно объяснить клиенту, что есть три варианта, выбирайте из них, другого не дано. Или пусть объясняет как это должно работать.
